# Always generating a NTLM instead of kerberos ticket

Tags: kerberos, ntlm

I have a C# client s below. I need to generate a kerberos token using this ticket. But it is always generating a NTLM token. The KDC is AD.

```
     public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  Uri uri = new Uri(args[0]);
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
  req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
  // Get the response.
 using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
   }

    }
```

The generated token is "Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl7II4gIAAgAuAAAABgAGACgAAAAGAvAjAAAAD1NFUlZFUklT". Can anybody instruct me what are the changes we should do to generate a kerberos ticket instead of NTLM one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before for the URL I have used the IP address. After using host name instead of IP address I could able to solve the problem